# pattern matching in regular expression (Perl)

Tags: regex, perl

Make a pattern that will match three consecutive copies of whatever is currently contained in `$what`. That is, if `$what` is `fred`, your pattern should match `fredfredfred`. If `$what` is `fred|barney`, your pattern should match `fredfredbarney`, `barneyfredfred`, `barneybarneybarney`, or many other variations. (Hint: You should set `$what` at the top of the pattern test program with a statement like `my $what = 'fred|barney';`)

But my solution to this is just too easy so I'm assuming its wrong. My solution is:

```
#! usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;


while (<>){
chomp;

if (/fred|barney/ig) {
    print "pattern found! \n";
}
}
```

It display what I want. And I didn't even have to save the pattern in a variable. Can someone help me through this? Or enlighten me if I'm doing/understanding the problem wrong?

Comment: `if (//g)` makes no sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example should clear up what was wrong with your solution:

```
my @tests = qw(xxxfooxx oofoobar bar bax rrrbarrrrr);
my $str = 'foo|bar';

for my $test (@tests) {
    my $match = $test =~ /$str/ig ? 'match' : 'not match';
    print "$test did $match\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
xxxfooxx did match
oofoobar did match
bar did match
bax did not match
rrrbarrrrr did match
```

**SOLUTION**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

# notice the example has the `|`. Meaning 
# match "fred" or "barney" 3 times. 
my $str = 'fred|barney';
my @tests = qw(fred fredfredfred barney barneybarneybarny barneyfredbarney);

for my $test (@tests) {
    if( $test =~ /^($str){3}$/ ) {
        print "$test matched!\n";
    } else {
        print "$test did not match!\n";
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$ ./test.pl
fred did not match!
fredfredfred matched!
barney did not match!
barneybarneybarny did not match!
barneyfredbarney matched!
```

Comment: can i use foreach instead? how is it different from "for" alone?

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated AFAIK, in perl5 they are the same when used as above.

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s="barney/fred";
my @ra=split("/", $s);
my $test="barneybarneyfred"; #etc, this will work on all permutations

if ($test =~ /^(?:$ra[0]|$ra[1]){3}$/)
{
    print "Valid\n";
}
else
{
    print "Invalid\n";
}
```

Split delimited your string based off of "/".  (?:$ra[0]|$ra[1]) says group, but do not extract, "barney" or "fred", {3} says exactly three copies.  Add an i after the closing "/" if the case doesn't matter. The ^ says "begins with," and the $ says "ends with."

EDIT:
If you need the format to be barney\fred, use this:

```
my $s="barney\\fred";
my @ra=split(/\\/, $s);
```

If you know that the matching will always be on fred and barney, then you can just replace $ra[0], $ra[1] with fred and barney.

Comment: (?:$ra[0]|$ra[1]) says group, but do not extract, "barney" or "fred" <- this line does this mean that compare them but dont save them to $1 variable?

Comment: Correct, by adding the ?: it means group and compare, but don't extract anything to $1,$2,...

Comment: Was there anything wrong with my answer? I understand accepting chrsblck's, but no upvote either?  Ours were kinda the same, but additionally, I explained what was going on instead of merely giving you the solution.

Comment: i didnt try your answer but im assuming it only accepts one instance of a $test? what if barneybarneybarney fredfredfred. Many instances

Comment: @SteveP. I think the main issue with your example is that it didn't follow the specs('|' delimited). How will your solution work for `$what = chris|fred|steve`?

Comment: @chrsblck: Ah, misread that, but you'd simply change what the delimiter is in the split (or have a set of allowed delimiters)...

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, I only put that one case in as an example.  It will work for everything that you want.

Comment: but in your example $test is not an array. is it ok to store a lot to it?

Comment: @ruggedbuteducated, I was simply showing one example.  Technically, `qw(fred fredfredfred barney barneybarneybarny barneyfredbarney);` doesn't contain all the cases, either.  If you wanted to test on a lot of possible strings, yes, using an array would be ideal, but I was just giving a single example.

Comment: @SteveP. Your solution isn't dynamic enough to handle a `n` strings. How does this work, `$r[0]|$r[1]` when you have 3 strings(`chris|fred|steve`) to match? You're just creating unneeded work.

Comment: @chrsblck fair enough, but I thought that it was constrained to two elements.  Had I considered n choices, I would've written it differently.  In retrospect, I should've taken that into account.